# How to fix this Madvertise SocketTimeoutException?

Tags: android, ads, banner-ads

I'm trying to make Madvertise ads work on my Android app.

I think I have everything setup in place: app item on their website, my actual token in manifest metadata, etc. As a matter of fact all preliminary messages from logcat seems to be ok both for `MadvertiseView` and for `MadvertiseTracker`.

Then MadvertiseTracker spits out a `"Response Code => 200"` message, while MadvertiseView comes with `"Could not receive a http response on an ad request"` and right after I can see a java.net.SocketTimeoutException.

A note: my test device connects to the net through my local wifi LAN, not through phone operator network. The app has wifi permissions too, and other Ad providers (e.g. AdMob) works fine in the same context.

I've searched on the web and also read all [Madvertise-related SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=madvertise) with no luck. I can of course provide a logcat if needed.

Anyone from Madvertise here around to give me some hints? Thanks to all

Comment: did you find any fix for this?

Comment: That seemed to be a temporary problem on their infrastructure. If I recall correctly, after asking to their support some days after, this was the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking to Madvertise support and receiving their response, that was a temporary problem on their infrastructure.
I did not have a chance to test that again in the aftermath.